# radiance at a grazing angle

Tags: radiometry

I was analyzing radiance equation, i.e. $L = \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\Omega \partial A \cos\Theta}$ and judging by the equation it appears that radiance just blows up as the angle $\Theta$ approaches grazing angle. But isn't it the other way around, that is, doesn't light intensity drop as the angle of incidence of a light ray approaches grazing angle (according to Lambert's cosine law)?

I understand that apparent area of an emitting object in a certain direction $\omega$ gets smaller as we approach grazing angle, thus, increasing the density of the radiant flux, which in its turn should increase radiance in that direction. But then again, I can't quite reconcile it with the reality. It's not like an object receives obscene amount of radiance at greater angles, right?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance#Mathematical_definitions 
There's this line at the end of the paragraph that says In general Le,Ω is a function of viewing direction, depending on θ through cos θ and azimuth angle through ∂Φe/∂Ω. For the special case of a Lambertian surface, ∂2Φe/(∂Ω ∂A) is proportional to cos θ, and Le,Ω is isotropic (independent of viewing direction). 
I think this is what you were asking about? I'm not sure about the answer so I'm adding it as a comment. I'll give an answer if you verify that I'm on the same page as you are

Comment: Frankly saying I am not entirely sure what do they mean by saying that ∂2Φe/(∂Ω ∂A) is proportional to cos θ. Do they mean that cosines cancel each other out (in case of a Lambertian surface)?